# Pass Value Checkbox without submitting a form with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to pass my check box without refreshing the page in codeigniter. The value that i want to pass is on a controller.

This one is my check box

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="red"> Car 1</label> &nbsp;
```

My Javascript textbox to toggle message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                    $(".1").toggle();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
                    $(".2").toggle();
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
                    $(".3").toggle();
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Then my notification messages

```
<div class="1 vxz">You have selected Car 1</div>
```

The polyline in the controller that i want to show when i tick the check box.

```
public function test() {
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $config['center'] = '-6.334, 106.85';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $polyline = array();
        $polyline['points'] = $this->GetMap();


        $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Mobil 1!';
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_polyline($polyline);

        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

$this->load->view('map') }
```

this is the view that show the maps.

```
<?php echo $map['js']; ?>
<?php echo $map['html']; ?>
```

Basicly the passing value is on the controller, how to get the value when i do click checkbox.

Comment: Hi, I think that the problem is in this part `$(".1").toggle();`, you can´t call a class or id in prototype or jquery starting with number

Comment: Hi @elddenmedio the problem it's not on the notification message, toogle it's working for notification message, but how that toogle can show my controller...